# How to create a secondary slide-out in Google Doc add on side bar in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Doc add-on that utilizes the sidebar: no problem there. When one uses the Google research add-on, there is an secondary slide out from the sidebar that shows a preview of a search result (see picture below) when clicked. I am hoping to replicate this behaviour, but I see nothing about it in the [api regarding size and limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars). I tried having a tooltip pop up on my links in the sidebar, but they appear cut off or under the main Google Doc palette. I have tried a bunch of other Google Doc add-ons to see if any of them replicate this functionality, but they don't. Before I spend hours on this, I want to first ask is anyone know if this is specific permission for Google's sidebar only, or can developers replicate this functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Research Tool](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2481802?hl=en) is a direct integration with Docs and Presentations, it's not a Google Apps Script add-on. The freedom to "slide out" within the document is not available to add-ons today.

As one alternative, you could use an accordion affect to collapse your "first page" and overlay the result page, still within the bounds of the sidebar.

A second alternative would be to use a non-modal window, where you'd have more freedom. (resizing there requires client-server exchanges, but is doable)